# Hash Function giving me extremely large numbers

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I am using the djb2 hash function for c, when I run a name through it I am getting hash numbers in the hundreds of thousands, I would like to get to be able to put this in a hash table using an array of a few thousand or something smaller at least inside a long. I am confused about how to get the function to give me smaller hashes while still having the integrity of the hash. Also I am confused about how to decide on the proper size of array to use for my hash table. Thank you in advance.

```
unsigned long hash(char* str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) 
    {
        c = (int) str[i];
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; 
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Put some code please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: "hundreds of thousands" _does_ fit into a `long`. And don't use unnecessary casts.

Comment: A hash table should be about double the size of the amount of data you expect to put in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your version of `djb2` returns an `unsigned long` (call the return variable `foo`, say), taking the modulus of that result modulo `n` using the expression

`foo % n`

will constrain the result from `0` to and including `n - 1`. This ought to have similar desirable statistical properties to the original hash value, and ought to be superior to a result obtained by integer division.