# Hash Function in C giving a negative number

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I am curious if the problem is that I need a different Hash Function or if there is a problem with my code. I need to hash words to store in a hash table, everything seems to be working good with the function but when I enter the words that are very long, some words are 45 characters, even though I am asking to get a unsigned long long returned to me, the hash I am receiving is a negative number.

Here is the code, your help is greatly appreciated.

```
unsigned long long hash(char* str);

int main (void)
{
    int numItems;
    char name[46];
    printf("Please enter how many items will be in your hashtable:");
    scanf("%d", &numItems);

    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        int key = 0;
        printf("Please type a name to be entered into the Hashtable:");
        scanf("%s", name);

        //run the word through a hashfunction (simple hashfunction)

       //print the hash number
        key = hash(name);

        printf("%d\n", key);
    }
}
unsigned long long hash(char* str)
    {
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        int c;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) 
            {
                c = (int) str[i];
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; 
            }
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hash Function giving me extremely large numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979114/hash-function-giving-me-extremely-large-numbers)

Comment: That's actually the same problem. Your code invokes undefined behaviour. And you fixed none of the issues commented on in your first post.

Comment: Your hash function returns an `unsigned long long`, which cannot be negative.  If that value is outside the range of `int`, however, as will often be the case, then converting it to a (signed) `int` has implementation-defined behavior that may include producing a negative result.

Comment: What use does it have to calculate the hash as `unsigned long`, but return it as `unsigned long long`, then assign it to an `int`? You should redesign your your interfaces to a consistent one.

Comment: thank you very much for your help this answered my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hash` function returns an `unsigned long long`, but you're storing the result in an `int`.

Change the type of `key` to `unsigned long long`, and print it using the `%llu` format specifier.

```
unsigned long long key = 0;
....
printf("%llu\n", key);
```

Also, the `hash` variable inside of the `hash` function should have type `unsigned long long`, and that variable should be renamed so as not to clash with the name of the function.

Comment: @TylerGotto [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).